# Onclick Not Working in When Put into If Statements

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I was assigned a project in class:

> "Create a 5x5 grid. Allow the user to click on the space between two
>   dots and draw the line between those two dots. To that end, I am
>   looking for two characteristics from your program: the ability to
>   tolerate being slightly off-line when clicking between dots, and the
>   ability to deal with ambiguity when clicking at a space that could be
>   in the vicinity of 2 or more spaces between dots."

So I am a beginner and don't really know an efficient way to do this, so I just wrote a long series of IF statements using the coordinates of each dot (I've only included 4 in this code). My issue is that I can't figure out how to get Onclick to work, as nothing happens when I click on the screen.

Any help with this or advice on a better way to code this is much appreciated!

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.speed(0)

def makeGrid():
  def dotLine():
    for i in range(5):
      t.begin_fill()
      t.fillcolor("black")
      t.circle(4)
      t.end_fill()
      t.penup()
      t.forward(50)
      t.pendown

  dotLine()

  t.penup()
  t.goto(0,0)
  t.setheading(90)
  t.forward(50)
  t.setheading(0)

  dotLine()

  t.penup()
  t.goto(0,0)
  t.setheading(90)
  t.forward(100)
  t.setheading(0)

  dotLine()

  t.penup()
  t.goto(0,0)
  t.setheading(90)
  t.forward(150)
  t.setheading(0)

  dotLine()

  t.penup()
  t.goto(0,0)
  t.setheading(90)
  t.forward(200)
  t.setheading(0)

  dotLine()

makeGrid()

ty = t.ycor()
tx = t.xcor()

t.goto(0,1)

#point 1
if screen.onclick == (ty == 0 and 0 < tx < 50):
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(50)
#point 2
if screen.onclick == (ty == 0 and 50 < tx < 100):
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(50)
#point 3
if screen.onclick == (ty == 0 and 100 < tx < 150):
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(50)
#point 4
if screen.onclick == (ty == 0 and 150 < tx < 200):
  t.pendown()
  t.forward(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `screen.onclick()` method doesn't work this way:

```
if screen.onclick == (ty == 0 and 0 < tx < 50):
```

Do you have any documentation for turtle?  The `onclick()` method takes the name of a function to call when a click happens, it doesn't return anything.  Also, one of your `turtle.pendown()` calls is missing its parentheses.

Finally, users can't click this accurately:

```
if screen.onclick == (ty == 0 and ...):
```

The odds of hitting 0 exactly are very low.  I've reworked your code below to get it to run.  Clearly you have more dots to make active:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

def dotLine():
    for _ in range(5):
        t.fillcolor("black")

        t.begin_fill()
        t.circle(4)
        t.end_fill()

        t.penup()
        t.forward(50)
        t.pendown()

def makeGrid():

    dotLine()

    t.penup()
    t.home()
    t.setheading(90)
    t.forward(50)
    t.setheading(0)

    dotLine()

    t.penup()
    t.home()
    t.setheading(90)
    t.forward(100)
    t.setheading(0)

    dotLine()

    t.penup()
    t.home()
    t.setheading(90)
    t.forward(150)
    t.setheading(0)

    dotLine()

    t.penup()
    t.home()
    t.setheading(90)
    t.forward(200)
    t.setheading(0)

    dotLine()

def onclick_handler(x, y):
    t.penup()

    # point 1
    if 0 < x < 50 and 0 < y < 50:
        t.goto(0, 0)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(50)

    # point 2
    elif 50 < x < 100 and 0 < y < 50:
        t.goto(50, 0)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(50)

    # point 3
    elif 100 < x < 150 and 0 < y < 50:
        t.goto(100, 0)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(50)

    # point 4
    elif 150 < x < 200 and 0 < y < 50:
        t.goto(150, 0)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(50)

    # point 5
    elif 200 < x < 250 and 0 < y < 50:
        t.goto(200, 0)
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(50)

screen = Screen()
t = Turtle(visible=False)
t.speed('fastest')

makeGrid()

screen.onclick(onclick_handler)

t.showturtle()

mainloop()
```

If the user has to click more points than currently included in your program, then I would go about this a different way. I would make each dot its own turtle, and then have the screen's `onclick()` event handler interrogate all turtles with the `turtle.distance()` method to find the two closest to the clicked point.  Then you don't have to do any of the decoding math as the turtles will handle it.

Comment: thank you! I'm not familiar with the turtle.distance() method, how does it differ from turtle.forward()?

Comment: @AlexaHalpert, in your turtle documentation you'll find that `turtle.distance()` doesn't move the turtle but rather measures the distance from the turtle to an x, y position, or another turtle.  Extremely useful!